# Is there an API for Android to delete the web browser's saved passwords?

Tags: android

Is there an API for Android to delete the web browser's saved passwords?

Comment: Be careful with this and keep it to a well-defined scope that's communicated to the user. If an all I installed started doing things like that unexpectedly, I'd be furious.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there is no "the browser", since the user can have several, and device manufacturers are welcome to replace the one from the Android open source project with one of their own. With respect to the Browser app from the Android open source project, there are no APIs to delete its saved passwords.